# Java Errors on HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, runtime-error

I wrote something similar to this and it was giving me an error. So I found this online and it still gives me an error. What Am I not doing correct ?

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    URL u = new URL ("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    HttpURLConnection huc =  ( HttpURLConnection )  u.openConnection (); 
    huc.setRequestMethod ("GET");  //OR  huc.setRequestMethod ("HEAD"); 
    huc.connect(); 
    int code = huc.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(code);
    }
}
```

The errors I am getting are

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.yahoo.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at urlCheck.UrlRTest.main(UrlRTest.java:30) " LINE 30 is huc.connect();
```

The error has been seen in SpringToolSuite & Ideone.com

Comment: This error means the host is not reachable from your network or doesn't exist. Check if yahoo.com is blocked in your network. When i ran this program locally it returned 301.

Comment: I assumed it could be a proxy error Hence I tried Ideone.com java to run it and received the similar error.